# Javascript Scope in Rails Folder Structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

in xxx.html.erb, implement a simple feature to select all checked items

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick=selectAll()>Select All</button>

<script>

function selectAll(){
  $(':checkbox').prop("checked", true);
}

</script>
```

However, when I try to extract the function selectAll to other files in rails, it does not work at all.

ex:

in xxx.html =>

```
<script src="/assets/xxx.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick=selectAll()>Select All</button>
```

in lib/assets/javascripts/xxx.js

```
  function selectAll(){
  $(':checkbox').prop("checked", true);
}
```

The browser will pop out Uncaught TypeError: selectAll is not a function ...

I think it could something be related to 'scope' but can not understand how it works . Very Thanks

Comment: Sounds like your JavaScript file is not being located. Have you tried
`src="/lib/assets/javascripts/xxx.js"`?

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 4:

Try to move into app/assets/javascript/xxx.js.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  selectAll();
});

function selectAll(){
  $(':checkbox').prop("checked", true);
}
```

Require in your app/assets/javascripts/applications.js if there is no `//= require_tree .` For instance:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require turbolinks
//= require xxx
```

I hope can help you.

Comment: have you called your application javascript in your layout?